# NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in destroy method of baskets controller - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a destroy method within a basket controller and it keeps giving me a `NoMethodError` for line 44 which is the following line:

```
if basket.to_a.collect{|item| [item[:product_id], item[:size]]}.include? [prod.id, params[:basket][:size]]
```

The `create` method works perfectly, so i'm not sure what the problem is in `destroy`??

**baskets_controller.rb**

```
class BasketsController < ApplicationController

def create
  prod = Product.find(params[:product_id])

  if basket.to_a.collect{|item| [item[:product_id], item[:size]]}.include? [prod.id, params[:basket][:size]]
    basket.each do |product| 
      if product[:product_id] == prod.id && product[:size] == params[:basket][:size] 
        product[:quantity] = product[:quantity] + params[:basket][:quantity].to_i
        flash.now[:success] = "Added to basket"
      end
    end 
  else     
    basket.add({product_id: prod.id, quantity: params[:basket][:quantity].to_i, size: params[:basket][:size]})
    flash.now[:success] = "Added to basket"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end    
end


def destroy
  prod = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @prod_name = prod.name
  if basket.to_a.collect{|item| [item[:product_id], item[:size]]}.include? [prod.id, params[:basket][:size]]
    basket.each do |product|
      if product[:product_id] == prod.id && product[:size] == params[:basket][:size]
        basket.delete(product)
        flash.now[:remove] = "Item removed from basket"
      end
    end 
  end       

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end    
end
```

`basket.to_a.collect{|item| [item[:product_id], item[:size]]}` prints the below in the log:
2

Medium

`basket.to_a.collect{|item| [item[:product_id], item[:size]]}.include? [prod.id, params[:basket][:size]]` returns the error

Many Thanks

Comment: either `basket` contains `nil` items (use `compact` to drop all `nils`, or that `params` do not contain a `:basket`

Comment: ok, so the basket definitely does contain an item and not sure what you mean by `params` not containing a `:basket` because the code is basically the same as in the `create` method which works fine

Comment: print each of those just to make sure...

Comment: then problem in `params[:basket][:size]`? Check out params in both cases

Comment: yea i gathered but how do i check them out like you say?

Comment: ok, so i don't understand why but `params[:basket][:size]` returns nothing...help?